# Banno Plugin Framework Bridge Alpha Status

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Reading the description on Github for the `banno-plugin-framework-bridge`:

> Some of this module's features are in an Alpha phase of development.

Are there plans to remove the Alpha label at some point? We're considering fitness of this library for a production application and would like to know what limitations we may encounter.

https://github.com/Banno/banno-plugin-framework-bridge

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a timeline for the alpha features (*Host events*, *App events*). We don't have any specific plans for breaking changes to the alpha features, but as it is an alpha there is also no guarantee against breakage as the features evolve.

In the meantime, the *Routing* feature is stable and usable.